# Particle System ignores vertex group

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

I have my fair experience with particle systems.

But currently i dont know whats going on.

Even the simplest plane, without any modifiers, that i subdive once wont work.
I added the loopcuts to try to fix it.

The vertex group itself is correct.
Is has a weight of 1.
Random or jittered dont work.

particle system
[image]

vertex group
[image]

Here is the blendfile

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49975

Comment: Please show your vertex group in the question selected in Edit Mode for the mesh.

Comment: Please show your work with a screen capture. People who want to answer and casual readers may want to see more visual info. Some people feel opening your file should be an option for the reader ... [not] a requirement.   A screen capture is small amount of work.

Comment: Added screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

- Please know Blender may include a face if even one vertex of a face is selected.  The whole face need not be selected.  This may be inconvenient for a brief moment.  The other hair placement tools are more precise.
- If you use a mesh with more vertices and a group, then you may see this pattern above.
- Precise hair placement can be done with UV Maps and Particle Edit mode tools for hair.  See image below.

[image]

In the image above you see Particle Edit Mode offered. Weight Painting is also offered.  The yellow arrow points to

Textures Panel associated with a Particle System while the Cycles Render is offered. Blender has

- Particle Edit offers the most precise placement on a 3D model
- Textures can control density and length as an abbreviated explanation
- Textures can have higher control Density than a low poly mesh
- Vertex Groups can control density and length as an abbreviated explanation
- Weight Painting a Vertex Group. Reasonable but least precise.

---

Consider

In the example below a placement of particles was desired on a single quad strip.  One solution was to duplicated the quad strip, place particles and move keep the meshes coincident.

[image]

- Perhaps your vertex group is empty or has a weight close to 0.0 zero.
- Perhaps you need to assign a weight of 1.0 to the group.

Comment: no the vertex group seems to be all ok